# SQL Union Select for alternate data

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I created an sql query with union select and here is the query to join the two columns into one.

```
(select top 10 FirstName from Users) union (select top 10 LastName from Users)
```

Here is the Result:
[QUERY RESULT 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9gif.png)

And here is the original data for the result 1 of union select.

[ORIGINAL DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7YtS.png)

So, here is my problem.
How do I select the data of each firstname and lastname with the same column but the first one is firstname and the second one is lastname. For example:

```
Tumbaga Temp   - <FirstName>
Villamor       - <LastName>
Jun            - <FirstName>
Villamor       - <LastName>
FN83           - <FirstName>
Lising Geron   - <LastName>
So on and so fort.
```

I am new in sql query. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your first names and last names don't match... What are you trying to do?

Comment: That is the original data from the database. The match of firstnames and lastnames are given in the "ORIGINAL DATA" from the second picture. How do I select into one column?

Comment: Select first and last name together. Fix the line break in the presentation layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We add a common row_number() to both parts to essentially group them, then order by this and the name type to display in clusters of first/last pairs

```
select 'First' as thename,
       Firstname,
       row_number() over(order by firstname) rn
from Users
union all
select 'Last',
       Lastname,
       row_number() over(order by firstname)
from users
order by rn, thename
```

If you only want the 1st 10, then wrap this and add a clause

```
select *
from
(
select 'First' as thename,
       Firstname,
       row_number() over(order by firstname) rn
from Users
union all
select 'Last',
       Lastname,
       row_number() over(order by firstname)
from users
)
where rn <=10
order by rn, thename
```

Comment: Thank you @JohnHC. The row_number is a big help to group the data.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use union, As per your description You have two columns 'firstName' and 'lastName' in a table and you want both in a single column. Just try the following query-:

```
select FirstName+' '+LastName as FullName from Users
```

SQL Server

Comment: I use the concatenation for the merge of the columns but not into one column for the output. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a column to both queries with your favourite data to be selected.

```
(select top 10 FirstName, 'FirstName' as NameType  from SysUser) union (select top 10 LastName, 'LastName' as NameType from SysUser)
```